# Notepad ++ CSS not linking to HTML (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, notepad++

I have seen a few of the answers on questions here.  Still can't find it.  Using notepad ++...

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"    
href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/
css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.j    s"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<scriptsrc="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.    js"></script>

<!-- the main css sheet -->
<link type="text/css" rel="main" href="main.css"> 

</head>


<body>  <p>This is a test.</p> </body>
```

main.css file

```
p{
    font-size: 250px;
 }
```

**The above css had no effect what so ever on the html**

I ran into the issue trying to add background image to bootstrap jumbotron. 
The stylesheet seems linked though, after viewing as source on google chrome.
What could be going wrong?

Below I have a picture of the file structure on my local machine.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH94g.png)..

I have put the css and html into the website folder...

Comment: why do you have the whitespace in the attribute value?

Comment: try this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">`

Comment: what are you referring to?

Comment: @Nilzone- I tried that... It still doesn't modify the text in between the p tags... I am pretty sure there are no mispells. lol

Comment: add a picture of your folder structure - that is most likely where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has nothing to do with the program you are using.

Looks like there could be multiple issues here.

1. Fix the line breaks in the middle of URLs `href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/
   css/bootstrap.min.css">`
2. Try this instead
3. Make sure the link source is correct, although it appears right in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your main.css file is in the css folder. in that case you need to put css/main.css